# How do you choose the device to perform operations on opencv-dnn?

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, opencl

How do you choose the device to perform operations on opencv-dnn?

In my environment, there are several connected devices that can run either opencl or the Inference engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to switch between different devices which support OpenCL computations, take a look onto `OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE` flag.

source: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/OpenCL-optimizations#opencv-opencl-configuration-options